# server crashes when I request any data from mangodb second or third time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, web-development-server

this is my code write is vs code.

```
const express=require("express");
const app= express();
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const Listing=require("./models/listings");
const path=require("path");
const methodOverride=require("method-override");

app.set("views",path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

main().then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to DB");
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Error while connecting to DB');
});

async function main(){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/wanderlust');
}

app.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log("Server is lisning on port 8080");
});

// Route Root
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hey I am Root");
}); 

// Route All Listings
app.get("/listings",async (req,res)=>{
    let allListings= await Listing.find();
    res.render("listings/index.ejs",{allListings});
});

// Route New Listing
app.get("/listing/new",(req,res)=>{
    res.render("listings/newListing.ejs");
});

// Route Show Listing
app.get("/listings/:id",async (req,res)=>{
    let {id}=req.params;
    let data=await Listing.findById(id);
    res.render("listings/show.ejs",{data});
});

// Route Save New Listing 
app.post("/listings",async (req,res)=>{
    let listing=new Listing(req.body.Listing);
    await listing.save();
    res.redirect("/listings");
});

app.get("/listings/:id/edit",async (req,res)=>{
    let {id}=req.params;
    let listing=await Listing.findById(id);
    res.render("listings/edit.ejs",{listing:listing});
});

app.put("/listings/:id",async(req,res)=>{
    let listing=new Listing(req.body.Listing);
    console.log(listing);
    res.send("Working");
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "wanderlust",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "its a bnb website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Vicky Girm",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.3"
  }
}
```

**And I'll get this error in my terminal**
It return a one promise but I'll use await and async.

When I start server using nodemon first time all routes are work properly but when I'll go second or third different pages or using same routes (like I'll go on /listing route and see three different listings first two are show me properly but third will show me error **Local host refuse to connect**) but when I restart the server using nodemon in my vscode then same page is working properly I don't know what's happen please help me.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: There isn't enough detail about your issue for someone to help. If you could copy and paste the full error message from your terminal then you might get more help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

**It appears that the failure to terminate the Mongoose connection after use may be the cause of the problem.**

Try adding the below code at last

```
const db = mongoose.connection;    
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  db.close(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB connection closed.");
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: I'll try it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).